# Use the floating action button in Nativescript/Angular project

Tags: angular, nativescript

In my mobile app, I have a message page and obviously I'd like to add a floating action button to write a new message. Of course I heard about this [plugin](https://github.com/bradmartin/nativescript-floatingactionbutton) allowing me to use the FAB but it seems to work only for Nativescript project. I've already tried using the registerElement function to be able to use the element in the html file (like I did for the [cardview](https://github.com/bradmartin/nativescript-cardview)) but it didn't give anything.

Maybe I'm doing something wrong. What am I missing ?

Comment: Hi Dat, add the code on how you are trying to use the plugin. Some others have gotten it working so it's possible but has to be done correctly in the ng2 context :)

Comment: @BradMartin In the component I have this line 
`registerElement("Fab", () => require("nativescript-floatingactionbutton").FloatingActionButton);`

And in the html file, I use the element like this : 
`<Fab (tap)="fabTap" icon="" ...></Fab>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

`registerElement("Fab", () => require("nativescript-floatingactionbutton").Fab);`

Comment: Ok now I managed to make the fab appears but even though in the css there are these 2 lines :

`horizontal-align : right` and `vertical-align : bottom`, the fab is always on the top right corner

Comment: My guess is your mark up has issues then. Open a new question if you can't figure out the positioning. Be glad to help

Comment: [Here](http://pastebin.com/B5PNdbdp) is the code (a portion of it) where I use the fab. So as you'll see, I have a tab where I have a list of messages and the fab is obviously to write a new message. With the way the code is right now, the FAB is in the right place but now I don't see the listview

Comment: You should try moving the FAB in the pull to refresh layout. It's just a positioning issue with your layout. If you get it on the same row as the listview then it will overlay the listview. I haven't tested anything but from quickly looking you should just try moving items around and you'll find out what works. Plus you'll learn some more about the layout system in NativeScript. Helped me a lot.

Comment: I guess that's the only way I'll solve my issue. Thank you for your time anyway

Comment: Solved it ! I just had to put the FAB inside an AbsoluteLayout (which I put below the Pulltorefresh layout) an add some css on the AbsoluteLayout so the FAB could be in the right place.